# SAS Authentication in ServiceBus using SOAP

Tags: azure, soap, biztalk, servicebus

I am trying to develop use SAS Authentication via ServiceBus using datacontracts. something like this: (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/)

```
ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProblemSolver));

sh.AddServiceEndpoint(
   typeof (IProblemSolver), new NetTcpBinding(), 
   "net.tcp://localhost:9358/solver");

sh.AddServiceEndpoint(
   typeof(IProblemSolver), new NetTcpRelayBinding(), 
   ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "**namespace**", "solver"))
    .Behaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior {
          TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider( "owner", "**key**")});

sh.Open();
```

However, I need to generate rules for SAS Authentication, (Send, Listen, Manage) via code: (something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205161.aspx)

This does provide the material but is over HTTP, can you give me pointers as to how I could use contracts while using SAS authentication?